# custom input instead of @Html.Editorfor

Tags: asp.net

I use `@Html.EditorFor(model=> model.Score)` in my "create" view but I would like to write

```
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>                           
    </select>
```

but how do I connect the select I write with the model.Score ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [DropDownListFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) instead of EditorFor.

In your case it could be:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedScore, Model.PossibleScores)
```

where names are self-described.

[An example of usage](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

Comment: Where do I get the values when I use DropDownListFor?

Comment: Check out my edit you can also find an example in the url from the end of my answer.